# Laravel 5.4 reply to the parent comment and display the comment under parent comment

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have an review table like this

```
mysql> select * from review;
+----+----------+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+------+---------+-----------+
| id | review   | rating | product_id | created_at          | updated_at          | approved | spam | user_id | parent_id |
+----+----------+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+------+---------+-----------+
|  1 | how much |      2 |         25 | 2017-05-05 12:02:02 | 2017-05-05 12:02:02 |        1 |    0 |      10 |      NULL |
|  2 | 20       |   NULL |         25 | 2017-05-05 12:02:35 | 2017-05-05 12:02:35 |        1 |    0 |      10 |         1 |
|  3 | ok       |   NULL |         31 | 2017-05-08 05:09:01 | 2017-05-08 05:09:01 |        1 |    0 |       9 |         2 |
|  4 | 30       |   NULL |         31 | 2017-05-08 05:25:47 | 2017-05-08 05:25:47 |        1 |    0 |       9 |         3 |
|  5 | 40       |   NULL |         31 | 2017-05-08 05:26:21 | 2017-05-08 05:26:21 |        1 |    0 |       9 |         4 |
|  6 | not fair |   NULL |         31 | 2017-05-08 05:27:16 | 2017-05-08 05:27:16 |        1 |    0 |       9 |         5 |
|  7 | 80       |   NULL |         31 | 2017-05-08 05:29:26 | 2017-05-08 05:29:26 |        1 |    0 |       9 |         1 |
|  8 | hi       |   NULL |         29 | 2017-05-08 05:37:25 | 2017-05-08 05:37:25 |        1 |    0 |       9 |      NULL |
+----+----------+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+------+---------+-----------+
```

when i try to add comments .It stores their parent id correctly what i want is now to display the comment under their parent comments...

How can i achieve this??

In my controller i am using 2 function

Function to display comments:

```
public function detail($id){
 $comments = Review::whereNull('parent_id')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
      $result = array();
      foreach($comments as $comment){
          $list = array();
          $list = array_merge($list, [['id' => $comment->id, 'parent_id' => $comment->parent_id, 'review' => $comment->review]]);
          //return $list;
          $result = array_merge($result, $this->get_child_comment($comment->comment_id,0));
          //return $result; 
      }
      return view('pages.product_detail', ['detail_dir_imgs'=>$detail_dir_imgs ,'seller'=>$seller, 'product_detail' => $product_detail, 'last4products'=>$products, 'sim_products'=> $sim_products,'reviews'=>$result,'getProduct'=>$getProduct]);

    }
    public function get_child_comment($pid,$level,$list=array()) {
              $sub_comments = Review::where('parent_id','=',$pid)->where('id','!=',$pid)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();  
              foreach($sub_comments as $sub_comment){
                  $space = "&nbsp;"; 
                  $sigm='-';
                  for($j=0; $j<=$level; $j++)
                  {
                      $space .=$space;
                  }
                  for($j=0; $j<=$level; $j++)
                  {
                      $space .= $sigm;
                  }
                  $sub_comment->comment = html_entity_decode($space, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8").' '.$sub_comment->comment;

                  $list = array_merge($list, array(['id' => $sub_comment->id, 'parent_id' => $sub_comment->parent_id, 'review' => $sub_comment->review]));

                  $list = $this->get_child_comment($sub_comment->id, $level+1, $list);
              }
            return $list;
          }
```

Function to store review:

```
public function review($id,Request $request){
        $userid = Auth::user()->id;
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $input = array(
          'review' => Input::get('review'),
          'rating'  => Input::get('rating'),
          'parent_id'  => Input::get('parent_id')
        );
        $review = new Review;
        $validator = Validator::make( $input, $review->getCreateRules());
        if ($validator->passes()) {
           $review->storeReviewForProduct($id, $input['review'], $input['rating'],$input['parent_id']);
          return redirect('product-detail/'.$id.'#reviews-anchor')->with('review_posted',true);
        }
        return Redirect::to('product-detail/'.$id.'#reviews-anchor')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
```

This is in my view:

```
 @foreach($reviews as $val) 
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                     <p>{{$val['review']}}   <span class="reply-comment">Reply</span></p>
                      {{-- Start Comment  --}}
                     <div class="comment-box" style="display:none;">
                       <form  action="{{ route('product.review',['id'=>$getProduct->id]) }}" method="post" id="comment">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{$val['id']}}" name="parent_id"  id="parent_id">
                        <textarea class="form-control animated" cols="50" id="new-comment" name="review" placeholder="Leave your comment here" rows="5"></textarea>
                        <div class="text-right">
                            <button class="bc-btn-cancel-review" href="#" id="close-comment">Close</button>
                            <button class="bc-btn-save-review" type="submit" id="review">Comment</button>
                        </div>
                       </form>
                     </div>
                    {{-- End Comment --}}
                 </div>
              </div>
            @endforeach
```

i want the output like in the image

[image]

Comment: show us your models did you define any relationships ? what do you pass to your view.

Comment: Can you show the code that you've worked so far.. ?

Comment: Edited my code...can you please check it

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do something like this, 
disregard the syntax, check the logic,
you can improve it by creating a query that will display all comments_id related to its parents and looping until the last associated parent_id is executed,  

HTML
       <div class="the_topic">
       </div>
       <div class="comments_here">
       </div>

    $.ajax({     
                type: "POST",
                url: 'url_to_controller/function/model_to_display_comment',
                data: comment_id
                dataType: json
                success: function (data) {
                             $.each(data, function(a,b){
                                  $("comments_here").append("<div id='"+b.id+"'>"+b.review+"</div>");  

                               b.parent_id = null : '' ? 
          $.ajax({     
                type: "POST",
                url: 'url_to_controller/function/model_to_display_comment',
                data: b.parent_id
                dataType: json
                success: function (data) {
                             $.each(data, function(c,d){
                                  $("."+d.parent_id).append("<div id='"+d.id+"'>"+d.review+"</div>");                               

                             })     


                        },
                 });
```

Comment: Can you please explain it more

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong the simplest way to achieve this using hasMany relation.
Make another table named subCommet.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|id  |  parent_id | comment | created_at  | updated_at  |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now in your Review.php model define relation

```
public function subcomments()
{ 
 return $this->hasMany('App\SubComment', id , parent_id);
}
```

then access subcomments in view template

```
@foreach($reviews as $val) {
 <div id="comment">{{$val->review}}</div>
 @if($val->subcomments->count() != 0)
  @foreach($val->subcomments as $subcomment)
      <div id="sub-comment">{{ $subcomment->comment }}</div>
  @endforeach
 @endif
 @endforeach
```

what you need is the hidden field with comment and reply textarea, after comment posted by user you need to check in your controller weather its a comment or a reply to some comment, then save comment in a table according to comment type, if comment is a reply to some comments then store it in subcomment table else store it in Review table.

Comment: When i try this it shows an error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Replace  `return $this->hasMany('App\SubComment', id , parent_id);` with  `return $this->hasMany('App\SubComment', parent_id ,id);`

Comment: The same errror

Comment: reviews must be an array, so your controller should be `Reviews = Review::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get(); return view::make('pages.product_detail',compact('Reviews'))`